# Border around ListView in code and TextView to right in Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, listview, textview, xamarin, border

I´m beginner, I would like how do I border around ListView (no in XML) and how do I textView to right (I used property Gravity and nothing, I have LinearLayout).

Thanks